# how to configure Magento in my local xampp

Tags: magento

Now i want to install magento, I downloaded the files from magentocommerce.com and extract it and run the installation file. In the second step once i entered the DBhost,Dbusername and DBpassword and navigate my installation to the next step it throws an error "*o Database server does not support the InnoDB storage engine.o Database connection error." Can anyone please guide me to install magento in my local.

Regards,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, there are some tutorials available on how to install Magento under Windows using the XAMPP stack, e.g. the one in the [Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_on_windows_with_xampp_and_wamp).

Note that even though mySQL supports InnoDB since mySQL 3.23.34a, you'll need to install at least mySQL 4.1.20 for current Magento versions (see [Magento System Requirements](http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements) for more detailed infos).